Newbie biking question: Tacx flow smart trainer compatibility with Decathlon Triban RC 100/120
Complete newbie to biking and indoor biking.
I'm looking to buy the Decathlon Triban RC 100 or 120 model. I can't seem to gauge the compatibility with the Tacx flow smart trainer (wheels on).
On the website it says that the tacx flow supports 10mm and 12mm axles and that it comes with a standard universal quick release axle skewer. It says that the skewer will work with most bikes that feature a quick release skewer. And on the bike says it is Quick-release mounting (9mm).
Seems like they are not compatible? Is there a way to solve this problem through an adapter or something?
